# in javascript open popup with href link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup

when I view this codes , iframe popup automatically open.
but I want to open iframe when I click "click me" button.
could you please help me ? I hope that its very easy trick but I am an amateur for javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var iframe = '<html><head><style>body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}</style></head><body><iframe src="http://www.euronews.com" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px)"></iframe></html></body>';
var win = window.open("","","width=1024,height=768,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
win.document.write(iframe);
</script>
<head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:load();"><b><font color="000">Click Me !</font></b></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code for you. You should probably not use an inline call, but here is how you would do it. Make sure to wrap your code in the `load` function so when you call `javascript:load()` it will complete the function.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function load() {
                var iframe = '<html><head><style>body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}</style></head><body><iframe src="http://www.euronews.com" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px)"></iframe></html></body>';
                var win = window.open("","","width=1024,height=768,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
                win.document.write(iframe);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:load();"><b><font color="000">Click Me !</font></b></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution could just be not creating the Iframe until the button is clicked:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
            function load() {
                var iframe = '<html><head><style>body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}</style></head><body><iframe src="http://www.euronews.com" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px)"></iframe></html></body>';
                var win = window.open("","","width=1024,height=768,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
                win.document.write(iframe);
            }
        </script>
    </head><body>
        <a href="javascript:load();"><b><font color="000">Click Me !</font></b></a></body>
</html>
```